# How can I downsample video to rgb24 with dithering in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

Setting `-pix_fmt` to a yuv colorspace will use Bayer dithering by default. I don't know how to change that behaviour.

When downsampling with `-pix_fmt` to an RGB colorspace like rgb24, no dithering is applied, resulting in ugly banding.

Edit:

I figured out how to control dithering to YUV colorspace. My issue was just that I misunderstood the ffmpeg filter syntax regarding `format`. It's not handled as a filter, but just tells the preceding filter what format to output:

```
-vf zscale:r=tv:d=error_diffusion,format=yuv420p
```

The issue is, zscale seems to be unable to dither at all when downsampling to RGB colorspace. 4 bpc RGB seems to be the exception, where ordered dithering is enforced. And I am unable to control dithering with the scale/swscale filter at all, using a global flag `-sws_dither ed` does not work.

`colorspace` filter can not output to RGB format.

Comment: Share full command and log.

Comment: @Gyan full command: `ffmpeg -i <infile> -pix_fmt bgr0 -vcodec ffv1 -level 3 -threads 16 -coder 1 -context 1 -slices 24 -slicecrc 1 <outfile> `
Whether the input file is 10-bit YUV or 10-bit RGB does not matter, dithering is never applied when downsampling to an RGB colorspace.